# "She is married to a dentist." In this sentence which type of parts of speech "married" is?

Tags: parts-of-speech

I often get confused.It's a simple question but please elaborate in deep.

Comment: This is easy to get confused about: *married* here is a past participle (passive participle) which has lost its verbal quality and is employed as an ordinary adjective--linguists call it a "deverbal" adjective. Check the answers to [this question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/116121/32) and  [this one](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/22071/32), and let us know if you need more explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example

> **married**

is a [*predicate adjective*](http://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/predicate_adjectives.htm) describing "**she**", they are often found after *be*-ing verbs and describe the subject.